# Мультиэкранность или кросэранность андроид

Tags: android, экран

Подскажите кто-нибудь, как сделать так что бы моё приложение работало на всех типах размерах экранов. Я создавал папки drawable-large-mdpi и прочее, но это через чур увеличивает размер самого приложения. Если есть какие-то уникальные способы, поделитесь ссылкой, только кроме этой [этой](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html)  именно оттуда я и брал "drawable-large-mdpi" и прочее.

Comment: это правильный способ. Все зависит от того, как много Вы решили туда втиснуть. Если там сотни картинок, то да, будет сильно увеличивать размер. Но можно картинки докачивать отдельно. Можно сделать свою версию приложений для каждого разрешения. А потом в маркете просто правильно подгрузить.

Comment: та картинок прилично, элементы управления - кнопки и т.д., фон, в общем интерфейс весь на картинках построен.

Comment: Значит нужно выверить все и найти вредителей. К примеру, некоторые картинки можно попробовать заменить системными (даже лучше для пользователя). Некоторые градиенты можно заменить drawable объектами. drawable с помощью простенького xml позволяют делать интересные векторные вещи. Следующий этап - использование 9-patch. И так до получения результата.

Comment: По дизайну там ничего изменять нельзя, малейший миллиметр расходится, всё сразу бракуют.

Comment: ну так в чем проблема? аккуратненько, под линеечку искать баланс между размером и трудозатратами.

Comment: ну, я себе в экселе нафигачил таблицу, которая мне генерирует дименс-строки под все разрешения, но этого мало, не знаю что с изображениями делать блин =(

Comment: Пожалуй в порядке бреда. 

А если попробовать масштабировать изображения?

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно описали выше. Для каждой группы плотности (density) и, если нужно разделять по размеру, то еще для каждой группы размеров своя картинка.

То есть если без разделения по размеру экрана, то:

```
res/drawable-ldpi/
res/drawable-mdpi/
res/drawable-hdpi/
res/drawable-xhdpi/
res/drawable-xxhdpi/
```

Если с разделением по группам размеров:

```
res/drawable-large-hdpi/
res/drawable-large-ldpi/
res/drawable-normal-hdpi/
res/drawable-normal-ldpi/
...
```

Я для упрощения этого процесса использую [вот эту утилитку](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/6MoSKTA1/0/blob?download). Проект не мой, но я под себя добавил группы размеров и коэффициент. Не помню где брал оригинал исходников, но могу своими измененными поделиться.

Выставляешь параметры, кидаешь в прогу нужные файлы, рядом генерятся папки с нужными наборами картинок. Коэффициент (себе для удобства зашил 85%) если отличается от 1, то перед генерацией набора картинок - оригинал ресайзится на эту величину. Sizes указывается только для имен папок, в которые генерятся наборы картинок - так удобнее, если делаешь конкретный набор для, например, normal. 9-patch так же генерит отлично.

Надеюсь, кому-то поможет.